# Changing Directory to Desktop

Tags: c++, windows, directory

I need to change my program directory to desktop regardless user name in C++ on Windows 7 and XP. I am currently using `_chdir()` function. I tried `_chdir("Desktop")` and `_chdir("desktop")` but it returned -1.

Is there way to do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Read the `%HOMEPATH%` environment variable, change to that directory and then to the desktop directory.